# how to manage alarms of my alarm clcok applications

Tags: android

I am developing a alarm application for android. 
Inputs from user : Time(Time dialog), Repeat days  and tone.

After user clicks on save I have to start a alarm using alarm manager.

Now I have lot of confusion. According to android setting alarm using same pending intent multiple times has no effect and only latest one takes effect.

How to start each alarm.

I have tried starting each alarm with different id for pending intent. How can I get unique id every time user creates alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use different request code values if you want multiple pending intents.

You could just increase the value of the request code by one each time you create your pending intent or you could convert the current timestamp value to an int and use that. Other than being unique, the actual value of the request code isn't that important.

That said, I doubt many alarm applications utilize multiple alarms. Most work by just keeping track of the next wakeup time and setting an alarm for that. When the alarm fires, a new one is created for the next wakeup time. To do this, a list of alarms, sorted by timestamp must be maintained. I suspect a tutorial or two could be found with some Googling.

Comment: U mean this  way.. Store all alarms in sqlite and start alarm using  `alarmmanager`  for the earliest one by sorting time column.